Approximating an integral using Taylor polynomials and controlling the error
I've just started working with Taylor polynomials in my analysis course, and got stuck on a problem involving integrals and Lagrange's error formula. The problem states that I should apporximate the integral $$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\sin(\cos t)dt$$
with an error of less than $(1/2) \cdot 10^{-3}$.
I struggle with how to start an exercise like this. My first approach was a kind of trial and error, where I inserted $\cos t$ into a Taylor polynomial for $\sin t$ of degree 4, hoping that I could do some analysis on the error term for this and that this would be lower than 0.005, and if not, I'd try with a higher degree. The 4th degree expansion for $f(t) = \sin t$ after inserting $\cos t$ yielded
$$T_{4}(\cos t) = \cos t - \frac{\cos ^3 t}{6}.$$
And for the error term, I got
$$ E_{4}(\cos t) = \frac{f^{(5)}(c)\cos^{5}t}{120}, \hspace{5 mm}c \in [-\left|t\right|, \left|t\right| ].$$
(Extra question, is the above notation correct? Specifically, I'm wondering how to write which interval $c$ belongs to.)
But from here, I don't really know what to do next. I wonder if the $f^{(5)}(c)$ gets affected by the insertion of $\cos t$ in to the error formula, or should this just be seen as the fifth derivative of $\sin t$? If it's the latter, could I just say that the whole error term is bounded above by $1/120$?
In the latter case, I guess I could integrate the error term from $\pi /3$ to $\pi /2$ and see if it is less than $0.005$. And I did give this a shot, which resulted in that the error when integrating should be less than $\pi / 720$, which actually is less than $0.005$, but I only established this due to having my calculator at hand, which I won't be having at my exam. I do think however that I could have done a rough division of $3.14/720$ and seen that this is less than $0.005$, but I do wonder if there is a whole other approach to this problem that I'm totally missing. It feels like it involves so many steps of guessing and trial and error, and I am a bit interested in how I should approach a problem like this, as it will be guaranteed to show up on my exam.
To sum up; I'm basically wondering what's the standard way to approach a problem like this?
Could we for example have done the expansion around $\pi /3$ or some other value?
Thanks for any help or tips on how to solve this problem!

$T_4(\cos t)$ is a good approximation in a neighbourhood of $0$

I think that you need to integrate before the analysis. Bur without a calculator ..... ?
